# Calculate $e^{1/4}$ using Maclaurin series with accuracy of 0.001

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to calculate $\sqrt[4]{e}$  with a deviation of less than $0.001$.

I was guided to use the Maclaurin series to solve this exercise.

So I've written down the series of $e$,

and now I don't have any idea how to proceed.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may know,

$$e^{1/4} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^k\,k!}$$

The error in using $N$ terms of the sum is roughly the $N+1$th term; that is

$$\text{error} \approx \frac{1}{4^{N+1} (N+1)!}$$

so find an $N$ such that $\frac{1}{4^{N+1} (N+1)!} \lt 0.001$

I get $N=3$; that is, the first 4 terms in the sum are accurate to within that error.

To elaborate:

$$e^{0.25} \approx 1.28403$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{3} \frac{1}{4^k\,k!} \approx 1.28385$$

$$\text{error} \approx 0.000171$$

Comment: @AndréNicolas: yes, you are correct and I made an edit.

Comment: I thought that method works only with leibniz series .. thanks!!!

Comment: @user1798362: you can use it when the terms in the series are decreasing sufficiently rapidly.  This is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

let $n\in \mathbb N_{\geq0}$, so by Maclaurin expansion there's $\theta\in(0,\frac{1}{4})$ such that

$$e^{\frac{1}{4}}=1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4^2.2!}+\ldots+\frac{1}{4^n.n!}+\frac{1}{4^{n+1}(n+1)!}e^{\frac{1}{4}\theta}$$
we look for $n$ such that the remainder
$$R_n=\frac{1}{4^{n+1}(n+1)!}e^{\frac{1}{4}\theta}\leq \frac{3}{4^{n+1}(n+1)!}\leq 10^{-3}$$
we find numerically
$$R_2\approx 7.8\times 10^{-3}\quad\text{and}\quad R_3\approx 4.8\times 10^{-4}$$
so we choose $n=3$ and we have
$$e^{\frac{1}{4}}\approx 1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4^2.2!}+\frac{1}{4^3.3!}\approx1.2839$$

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute 1/4 for the value of x in each term.
By the time you get to the 5th term the value is 0.000163 which is much smaller than your tolerance. Subsequent terms, with the factorial on the bottom, will get much smaller very rapidly.
Their total will not affect the first 3 decimal places of the answer.
Essentially you only need 4 terms of the series.